# What part is a parameterized type?

Tags: java

I understand what `ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();` does, but which part is call the parameterized type?

The type variable on the left side of the assignment operator or the constructor on the right side? When they say parameterized type, do they mean the way it's constructed where you definea parameterized type inside the angular bracket such as `ArrayList<String>()`?

Because I know regular `List = new List()` doesn't have a parameterize type.

Question is: which part is the parameterized type? The left or right side: `ArrayList<String> list1 or new ArrayList<String>()`;

Answer (score 5):

A [type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html) is either a class, an interface, an array, or an enum (well primitives as well, but those don't apply here).

A parameterized type is any of those types declared as using generics. For example, in

```
public class MyCustomGenerics<T,E> {
   ...
}
```

`MyCustomGenerics` is a parameterized type.

Therefore, `ArrayList` is a parameterized type. It is declared as

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
```

In

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

`String` is the type argument.

Comment: This answer should be accepted.Sotirios has explained clearly!